# PhantomJS / Javascript: write to file instead of to console

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

From PhantomJS, how do I write to a log instead of to the console?

In the examples https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Examples, it always (in the ones I have looked at) says something like:

```
console.log('some stuff I wrote');
```

This is not so useful.

Comment: Did you try using HTML FileSystem API as you would in normal browser?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I figured it out:

```
>phantomjs.exe file_to_run.js > my_log.txt
```

Comment: while this works, it's going to also write potentially unwanted content to the file such as javascripts errors and other phantomjs errors. You're better off with Arun's answer so that you can control *exactly* what gets written.

Comment: that does not write to file using phantomjs. that is just standard stdout redirection, and so is not an answer to the question.

Comment: good for quick and dirty viewing of the console.log messages though.

Comment: This solution does not create UTF-8 output hence creates problems with special characters

Comment: Nice working solution without even having to change code.

Answer (score 43):

The following can write contents to the file directly by phantomjs:

```
var fs = require('fs');
   try {
    fs.write("/home/username/sampleFileName.txt", "Message to be written to the file", 'w');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    phantom.exit();
```

The command in the answer by user984003 fails when there is some warning or exceptions occurred. And sometimes does not fall into our specific requirements because in some codebase I am getting the following message always which will also be logged to that file.

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

Answer (score 10):

You can override original console.log function, take a look at this :

```
Object.defineProperty(console, "toFile", {
    get : function() {
        return console.__file__;
    },
    set : function(val) {
        if (!console.__file__ && val) {
            console.__log__ = console.log;
            console.log = function() {
                var fs = require('fs');
                var msg = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                    msg += ((i === 0) ? '' : ' ') + arguments[i];
                }
                if (msg) {
                    fs.write(console.__file__, msg + '\r\n', 'a');
                }
            };
        }
        else if (console.__file__ && !val) {
            console.log = console.__log__;
        }
        console.__file__ = val;
    }
});
```

Then you can do this:

```
console.log('this will go to console');
console.toFile = 'test.txt';
console.log('this will go to the test.txt file');
console.toFile = '';
console.log('this will again go to the console');
```

Comment: This is great because this will not only put the phantom.js output into the file but all other console.log entries as well, making it possible to debug the tests themselves. One addition would be to (still) also output to the console by adding the line `console.__log__.apply(console, arguments);` after the `fs.write()` thereby allowing the normal console output to be processed by normally CI runners.

Comment: One more thing: the `fs.write` line today is 
`fs.writeFileSync(console.__file__, msg + '\r\n', { flag: 'a' });`

Comment: Why isn't this selected as the answer. Just asking, why the other one got selected, how's that better than this?

Comment: @TriptiRawat I think the other (worse) answer got selected because the OP answered their own question