# Using CasperJS to log insecure resource errors on https pages

Tags: https, tdd, casperjs

With CasperJS, I would like to add some test coverage for https pages that load insecure resources over http and produce the following Chrome console error:

"The page at 'https://www.mysite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://cdn.mysite.com/images/chucknorris.gif': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS."

Using CasperJS, how would you write a test to crawl an array of paths on a specific domain, identify which of those have insecure resource errors and log the insecure resource console error to a file?

**edit:** as noted by Chris, `fs = require('fs');` should be used to allow writing the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at var **fs = require('fs');** by default JavaScript does not write to your file system or it could be a major security risk so enabling this feature from phantom will allow you to write cookies files etc... Aside from using that to write log files you would have to read the output from casperjs using something like Python.

As far as how to crawl the domain, you would need to evaluate the domain to figure out what urls do I need to visit and or what urls do I need to click to bounce from page to page. this is a domain specific question only you will be able to answer after your analysis.

Comment: This will not be crawled from the live server. I will sharpen up the question to address using require('fs') and given an array of paths to check for errors. It does look like [PhantomJS 1.9 and above can write to a logfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654283/phantomjs-javascript-write-to-file-instead-of-to-console) without need for Python.